Cannot create .NET MAUI project from Linux Ubuntu
I just became aware that Linux users can create MAUI apps, so I followed the steps listed in these resources:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/net-maui-on-linux-with-visual-studio-code/ba-p/3982195
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D2vUYUIqFU

So far, I have installed all the necessary SDKs for C# and MAUI. I can confirm this by typing dotnet --info

And dotnet workload list

So, I have all the SDKs and variables needed to run .NET MAUI. The problem occurs when I try to select the project to create. .NET is not an option just everything else like ASP.NET projects, but no MAUI.

Here the extensions I have installed:


I don't understand what I'm missing, and switching to Windows or Mac won't be an option for me for a while. Does anyone have an idea of what it could be?
Thanks!

Have you Installed the .NET MAUI extension in VS Code?
You can open Visual Studio Code, then click on the Extensions icon and enter .net maui. The top result should be the official .NET MAUI extension from Microsoft.

@ShuowenHe-MSFT yeah, I have edited my question by adding photos of all the extension of .NET I currently have

Have you successfully completed step 7(Activate C# Dev Kit) in the  .NET MAUI on Linux with Visual Studio Code? According to the documentation, you can create the maui project normally after completing this step

Yes, I was able to login through the login. One interesting thing is that I can create a MAUI app from the terminal, using dotnet new maui but no way to build or debug

You can try to check if the Open JDK version is changed to 11, then restart VS code.
